# How do you scale images/sprites properly in Godot?

Tags: game-engine, scaling, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to create a 2D cross-platform game (primarily for android & ios in portrait mode, however compatibility with a tablet/desktop would be a bonus) and I'm trying to wrap my head around scaling of my sprites.

I've looked online, and I've ended up setting the following in my Project Settings > Stretch

- 'Mode' : 2D
- 'Aspect' : keep-height.

According to https://www.mydevice.io the viewport of my android phone is 360 x 640px (the standard 16:9 ratio for mobiles). But obviously phones/tablet screens come in all sorts of dimensions.

If I wanted to create a sprite with a width exactly 1/3rd of that of my screen/viewport, how should I go about doing this? Should I be creating multiple sprites of various dimensions (in say, GraphicsGale) to account for different screen sizes, or should I be purely doing this scaling in Godot?

I know there's a 'scale' property in Godot, but I can't see a way of setting my image width and height via pixels or by a percentage of the viewport.

Comment: Does this help?
https://godotengine.org/qa/3626/how-set-sprite-texture-size

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the sprite size depending on the viewport height and width ?

```
$sprite.size.x = get_viewport().size.x * 0.33
$sprite.size.y = get_viewport().size.y * 0.33
```

You can check out this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/b0lj5u/possible_noob_question_how_to_change_the_size_of/) if this is not working.